# Subtracting a Day from a Full Date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to subtract 1 day from a string value of a date I have,
for example when I subtract a day from 2017/01/01 instead of getting 2016/12/31 I end up getting a value of 2017/0/31.

Below is the code I'm working on:

```
                var inputDate = "2017/01/01";
                var splitClndr = inputDate.value.split("/");
                var clndrDate = new Date(splitClndr[0], splitClndr[1], splitClndr[2]);
                clndrDate.setDate(clndrDate.getDate() - 1);
                var nd = new Date(clndrDate);
                var dd = nd.getDate();
                var mm = nd.getMonth();
                var y = nd.getFullYear();
                var newFormattedDate = y + '/'+ mm + '/'+ dd;
                operatorDate.value = newFormattedDate;
```

The value I get in the variable newFromattedDate is 2017/0/31, how can I make the result of subtracting a day to 2016/12/31 instead?

Comment: month is zero based ... add one to `nd.getMOnth()` - you'll also need to subtract one from `splitClndr[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months in javascript are zero-based, so `0` is January:

```
new Date(2017, 1, 1) >> Wed Feb 01 2017
```

You need to compensate for this, both when creating your `clndrDate` and when concatenating your string.

```
new Date(splitClndr[0], splitClndr[1]-1, splitClndr[2])

...

var mm = nd.getMonth()+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just substract directly from the date:

```
var d = new Date('2017/01/01');
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
var newDateString = d.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(newDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setDate` method to subtract the number of days you want.

```
var inputDate = "2017/01/01"; 
var newDate = new Date(inputDate); 
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 1);
console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   var inputDate = "2017/01/01";
   var splitClndr = inputDate.split("/");
   var clndrDate = new Date(splitClndr[0], splitClndr[1] - 1, splitClndr[2]);
   var past_time = clndrDate.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1; // last 1 will be day
   clndrDate.setTime(past_time);
   console.log(clndrDate);
```

Working [jsfilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3p2gb7p/11/).